# How do you find the height of the recurrence tree $T(n,k)=T(\frac{n}{2},k)+T(n,\frac{k}{4})+nk$

Tags: trees, recurrence-relation

I try to find tree height such that first i define:
$H(n,k)=H(\frac{n}{2},k)+H(n,\frac{k}{4})+1$
then find height of left branch of tree=logn & right branch of tree=logk,but now why height of tree is equal to logk+logn?i guess height of tree is Max(logn,logk)why my geuss is not true?

Comment: The height of your recurrence tree is roughly $\max(\log_2n,\log_4k)$. Your recurrence for $H$ should have a $\max$ instead of a $+$.

Comment: please if you can explain why my argument(my guess) is true?in  solution manual used + instead of max but i say it's not true

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive definition of a height of a tree $T$:

- If $T$ is a leaf, then its height is 0 (some people prefer to use 1).
- Otherwise, the height of $T$ is the maximum height of any of its children, plus 1.

Equivalently, the height of a tree is the maximum length of a root-to-leaf path (in edges; if you measure it in vertices, leaves should have height 1).

This makes it clear that the correct recurrence for the height is
$$
H(n,k) = \max(H(\tfrac{n}{2},k), H(n,\tfrac{k}{4})) + 1,
$$
with an appropriate base case. The solution is roughly $\max(\log_2 n, \log_4 k)$, depending on the base case.

Comment: $H(n,k) = \max(H(\tfrac{n}{2},k), H(n,\tfrac{k}{4})) + 1$ is not correct.