# Accurate height of recursion tree for given recursion

Tags: recurrence-relation

We are trying to find height of following recursion formula in terms of $n,k$:

\begin{gather*} 
T(n,k)=T(\frac{n}{2},k)+T(n,\frac{k}{4})+nk
\end{gather*}
\begin{gather*} 
T(n,1)=T(1,k)=O(1)
\end{gather*}

I read [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905431/height-of-recursion-tree-for-tn-k-tn-2-k-tn-k-4-kn) , and [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131944/how-do-you-find-the-height-of-the-recurrence-tree-tn-k-t-fracn2-ktn), but i think neither of answers are true.

Comment: Why do you say they are not true?  Can you [edit] your question to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Look at recursion tree, as you see we go down until we are be in $T(2,k)$ that is equal to decease $n$  $\log n-1$ times to become $n=2$. So that branch have height $\log n-1$ Because we are not in base case then we can continue, but on $k$ we recurse. Because of value $n$ not be changed we can go down until $k=1$ that this branch have height $\log_4 k$. Now we can say height of $T(n,k)$ is is summation of two branches:
\begin{gather*} 
O(\log_2n+\log_4n)
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Now, this recurrence formula is not all well-formed, but assuming that it really means

> $T(n,k) = T(\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor,k)+T(n,\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor) +nk$

, the height of the recursion tree becomes $\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor + \lfloor\log_2(k)\rfloor - 1$
. The deepest leaves in the tree will then always have one of $n$ and $k$ being 1, and the other being 2 or 3.